# Cannot build basic websharper app on dotnet core and ubuntu

Tags: f#, .net-core, websharper

I'm playing with websharper with the basic project template (websharper-web) on dotnet core 2.2 on ubuntu 16.04.

I've just used the basic template to create the project:

```
dotnet new websharper-web -lang F#
```

When I try and build I'm getting a generic error:

```
1>/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/FSharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(263,9): error MSB6006: "wsfsc.exe" exited with code 8. [/home/barrys/Documents/code/FSharp/WebSharperTest/WebSharperTest.fsproj]
1>Done Building Project "/home/../Documents/code/FSharp/WebSharperTest/WebSharperTest.fsproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"/home/../Documents/code/FSharp/WebSharperTest/WebSharperTest.fsproj" (Build target) (1:10) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/FSharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(263,9): error MSB6006: "wsfsc.exe" exited with code 8. [/home/barrys/Documents/code/FSharp/WebSharperTest/WebSharperTest.fsproj]
```

I'm getting loads of these types of warnings on the build output as well but not sure what the significance is:

```
 1>_HandlePackageFileConflicts:
     Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.0.0/ref/netcoreapp2.0/System.AppContext.dll' and 'Reference:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.appcontext/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.AppContext.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.0.0/ref/netcoreapp2.0/System.AppContext.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.2.0.0' is greater than '4.1.0.0'.
```

Can anybody please tell me whether I should be able to build and run websharper on ubuntu and if so give me more information on what the build errors mean and how to fix?

Thanks